# How allow attribute class on img tag for allowedContent config?

Tags: image, class, configuration, ckeditor

i write for a problem with the use of allowedContent config option.
I set the instance of my ckeditor with this option:

```
        allowedContent: 'p; strong; em; u; s; sub; sup; ul; ol; li; blockquote; a [!href, title, target, rel]; hr; h2; h3; pre; img [!src, alt, height, width, title, id];',
```

How i allow the insertion of "class" attribute for img tag? In my html code read from db i have this:

```
        <img alt="xx" width="100" height="100" src="yyy" class="myclass" />
```

but when i load it into ckeditor class attribute is stripped out.

I've tried

```
        img [!src, alt, height, width, title, class, id]
```

and

```
        img (cke-xyz) [!src, alt, height, width, title, id]
```

but don't work.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow specific class names:

```
img(classname1, classname2)[attr1, attr2]
```

or if you want to allow all classes:

```
img(*)[attr1, attr2]
```

Read more in the documentation: [Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules).